# Invariant Violation: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm working swith React and Webpack on a server side rendering App. When open my localhost page the page render this error :

> [[AWarning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.

However my importation is good and don't know why the server returns me this error.

Here my App.js :

```
   const AppRoute = () => { 
            if(process.env.BROWSER){
        return <Provider store={store}> 
        <BrowserRouter history={ history }> 
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={App} exact />
            <Route path="/post_entry" component={postEntry} exact />
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter> 
        </Provider> 
            }

      else { 
    return
            <Provider store={store}> 
            <ServerRouter history={ history }> 
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={App} exact />
                <Route path="/post_entry" component={postEntry} exact />
            </Switch>
            </ServerRouter> 
            </Provider> 

        }
        }

    export default AppRoute  // great default export
```

my server.js :

```
import AppRoute  from "../app/Router"; // great default import

 <body>
    <div id="root">${renderToString(<AppRoute/>)}</div> 
  </body>
```

my browser.js :

```
import {render} from "react-dom" ;
import  AppRoute  from "../app/Router"; // great default import

render( <AppRoute/> {...} )
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, if somebody got any hint would be good,
Thanks

Comment: You also need to import all the react router components in the file that defines `AppRoute`

Comment: Also, are the `App` and `postEntry` components used by your router defined somewhere?

Comment: everything works now on a route level, is just my component that seems doesn't mount because I receive this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined` despite my view is well rendered, think it just about make some settings on the Redux side